# how to debug/develop azure function in local VisualStudio, passing in csv file. (normally csv file gets passed from AzureLogicApp)

Tags: azure-functions, postman

If I have an Azure Logic App call an Azure function, passing a csv file to the function, how can use my local VS debugger to step through code and develop?

I am trying to use PostMan but I don't know how to trigger the function on my local pc.  Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I can trigger and step through code?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to use PostMan but I don't know how to trigger the function on my local pc. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I can trigger and step through code?

There is no way you can use postman unless you are publishing it to azure. To debug locally you can use 'Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer' and check if they are reading the files. Additionally, while you are running only azure functions you can keep the *Breakpoints* normally and observe how the debug is happening.

Here is the code that I referred to from this [blog](https://kiranjoy.blog/2019/02/25/azure-functions-blob-storage-trigger-to-process-csv-in-csharp/comment-page-1/)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using CsvHelper;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace BlobTrigger
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("expenses/{name}.csv", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream myBlob, string name,
            [Table("Expenses", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] IAsyncCollector<Expense> expenseTable,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
            var records = new List<Expense>();
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var tr = new StreamReader(myBlob))
                {
                    using (var csv = new CsvReader(tr))
                    {
                        if (csv.Read())
                        {
                            log.LogInformation("Reading CSV");
                            csv.ReadHeader();
                            while (csv.Read())
                            {
                                var record = new Expense
                                {
                                    Amount = double.Parse(csv.GetField("Debit")),
                                    Title = csv.GetField("Title"),
                                    PartitionKey = "Expenses",
                                    RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                                };
                                expenseTable.AddAsync(record).Wait();
                                records.Add(record);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Expense : TableEntity
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Before executing the code you need to install 'Csv Helper' in order to read the CSV file.

> If I have an Azure Logic App call an Azure function, passing a CSV file to the function, how can use my local VS debugger to step through code and develop?

If you want to develop a logic app First you need to Design your flow in the portal and then connect to your account > Open your logic app (Open with Logic App)

from there you can do the same thing that you do in the portal i.e. Run trigger. For debugging you can actually check the run triggers where it has failed and monitor every step from there.

For more information, you can refer [Edit and manage logic apps by using Visual Studio with Cloud Explorer - Azure Logic Apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/manage-logic-apps-with-visual-studio)

### **Updated Answer**

I'm sending the CSV file using postman and hitting the logic app which is connected to functions.

here is my logic app flow
[image]

[image]

[image]

for debugging you can follow this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions/).

Comment: thank you.  I'm alittle confused on AzureFunction part.  The LogicApp transmits the csv file to the AzureFunction.  Which I believe makes the Function HTTPtriggered.  It is not a blob storage trigger.  So if the function is a httptriggered, how would I debug code in VS?

Comment: @solarissf I have updated the answer. please take a look at it and revert back if you need any further assistance.